# Is it possible to get Derived class properties at generic class in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, class, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class and interface of base class type [Event]. There are number of classes derived from this base class [Event]. I am able to get the properties of the base class[Event] in my generic class method. However, I am not able to get the derived class property. Few properties are same in all the derived classes and i would like to access those properties in my generic class method.

Is there any way to do this.

Thanks

```
public class Online<T> : IOnline<T> where T : Event

{

    public T message { get; set; }
    public void Process(IDomainContainer container, T message)
    {
      var Eventproperty= message.Eventproperty; // no error
       var derivedclassproperty= message.derivedclassproperty; //compile time error
    }

}
```

Comment: If those properties are the same in all derived classes, why aren't they declared in the base class?

Comment: If you are expecting to be able to use properties other than those defined in `Event`, then either put them in `Event` or you likely need to rethink your implementation.

Comment: "Is there any way to do this" yes, by casting the object to the correct type. But how you want to find out which type is the correct one is up to you

Comment: the common properties in derived class are not defined in base class as there are other derived classes which does not need them - Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: yes we can cast. But how can we cast in generic class -MindSwipe

Answer (score 0):

Declare a base class EventBase derived from Event, add the common properties from derived classes and change Online to use EventBase instead of Event.